# Printing paragraphs with textnodes

Tags: javascript, html

I have this assignment where I'm supposed to make a sort of printing machine in HTML/javascript, and I got stuck on the node/DOM part(it is hard!).
So I'm supposed to make a paragraph node and a textnode in addParagraph, and the link them. My global variable 'ntext' is going to keep track of the textnode and every new paragraphnode should be added to the DOM  attribute with the class 'output'.

And in the addLetter(c) function addParagraph() function should be called again if ntext is undefined. If its not undefined, it should print the value (which it does not).

```
var ntext;

function addParagraph() {

  var textnode;
  var paragraphn;
  var div;

  paragraphn = document.createElement('p');
  textnode = document.createTextNode("");
  paragraphn.appendChild(textnode);

  ntext = textnode;
  div = document.getElementById("output");
  div.lastChild(paragraphn);
}
```

That's the paragraph part.

And this is the print part.

```
function addLetter(c){
if (ntext == 'undefined') {
  addParagraph();
}

 ntext.firstChild.appendData(c);
}
```

Oh, and the HTML5 code is 100% correct as it was my teacher who made it, my task is to make the javascript only.

Of course I forgot to add my question, well, this whole thing won't add the letters I click, and I don't know why!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It does not work, it won't add the letters i click

Comment: Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U83S4/

There's the fiddle, comments are in Swedish which is my native language, just ignore it. @Dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition `ntext == 'undefined'`. You are testing against a string `'undefined'` instead of a [undefined property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined). Change it to:

```
if (ntext == undefined) {
```

Comment: It did not work, unfortunately, but thanks, sure did correct an error!

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tag you @mechanicalfish

Comment: Yeah, there are other problems with your code and I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to do, but look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ukhk3/1/ Is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, it was such a small error, silly me. Big thanks!